# How to see variables of running IPython cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've run an IPython cell and it seems to take a long time.

Is there a way to attach to this running kernel?
I'd like to see the values of the current loop iteration variable while the cell still has not finished.

Answer (score 0):

By command mode?
IPython has a set of predefined ‘magic functions’ that you can call with a command line style syntax. There are two kinds of magics, line-oriented and cell-oriented. Line magics are prefixed with the % character and work much like OS command-line calls: they get as an argument the rest of the line, where arguments are passed without parentheses or quotes

Comment: I cannot run anything in this notebook, since the cell is still running. It happens that I run cells, they take a long time and I'd like to see what's going on without stopping the cell.